# How to share data between two pages via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

What I have is a aspx page that loads other aspx page inside a Jquery Dialog.
It works fine, but I'm having douts about how to send js data from one page to the other.

I know there are some workaround solutions, but what is the best practice for that?

Comment: once you've loaded the second page's content into a jQuery Dialog (or any other container) within the first page, then essentially you have got one single page loaded into the browser. Page 2 becomes simply one part of Page 1. So at that time your script can easily refer to elements from either part.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I notice that. But would a global variable be the best way to do it? Maybe setting some .data('something') to the dialog and getting it at the page 2? I don't know. I'm looking for a pretty solution.

Comment: Whenever I have to pass data between pages, if I am not already using a framework that handles the routing then I use localStorage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @GuilhermeHodge that could be one neat way. It's difficult to say what the best thing is without knowing a bit more detail of the requirements to be honest. Are you trying to inject content in the elements of Page 2? Or triggering events on it? Or something else? There are lots of ways of doing things. A global variable would work but I agree it's pretty kludgy.

Comment: Its a simple thing; Page 2 is a create/edit page. So, when a call it from an existing item I want the page to be filled up. 

I can manage that just sending the itemId by url when loading page 2, but this would be the only case I'd use embedded variables in this project. Wouldnt it be a bad practice?

Comment: What about send the itemId by URL (page2.aspx?itemId) Then embed it into the HTML.
When finish loading page2, I then, get the item info via ajax, passing the embedded itemId.

Too kludgy?